# New tags that come from migrated questions

Tags: discussion

Does it make sense for a tag that does not exist in one SE site to be migrated along with the question? For example, a new tag was created ifttt. I thought it was a goof, but when I looked at the only question under that tag, it was migrated from Web applications and stands for if-this-than-that and has a tag wiki on that site.

What is suggested when a tag like this shows up?

Answer (score 4):

The [question was migrated](https://superuser.com/questions/575110/how-do-i-get-the-ifttt-gtalk-channel-to-work-with-a-google-apps-account) **to** Web Apps. The tag started here.

Tags from other sites that don't exist here are not migrated. They are removed.

Comment: Oops, you are right. That tag can go though correct?

Comment: That tag will die when the question is deleted. But someone can ask a new question until then using it if it fits.